# How to add fragment from Palette in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Before I can add <fragment> from Custom section.

[image: Custom section in Palette]

But now in Android Studio 2.2.3 <fragment> in Layouts section. I create Fragment class and try to add <fragment> in main_activity.xml (Design mode). But I can't find my class Fragment1.

[image: Where fragment class]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the layout section and you will see an option for fragment. Drag and drop this into the activity. Then, a window will open up with all the available fragments. Here you will find your fragment.